# "ruled off into squares" — What does that mean?

Tags: phrase-requests, meaning-in-context

I don't know what the phrase means in the following context:

> A procedure that is guaranteed to lead to the desired output in a
> finite sequence of steps is called an "algorithm" or "effective
> procedure." Turing envisioned a machine consisting of a read/write
> head operating on an indefinitely extendable tape **ruled off into
> squares.** — [Irreducible Mind: Toward a Psychology for the 21st Century](https://books.google.com/books?id=6gS_LcIjFMsC&pg=PA7&lpg=PA7&dq=%22A%20procedure%20that%20is%20guaranteed%20to%20lead%20to%20the%20desired%20output%20in%20a%20finite%20sequence%20of%20steps%20is%20called%20an%22&source=bl&ots=HoJz_93R4A&sig=ACfU3U1dc_M1HYMG6P_2HC0ygbAPWdikEw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjDgczBvKD4AhX2pIkEHQiwD0IQ6AF6BAgDEAI)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relevant definition of "ruled" here is:

> (of paper) marked with parallel straight lines.
> —[Oxford Dictionaries/Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/ruled)

Because Turing thought this up in 1936, he was describing a machine like this that uses actual paper tape:

> [image: finite state machine, showing a read/write head passing over tape that can be moved in either direction]
> [What is a Turing Machine?](https://www.i-programmer.info/babbages-bag/23-turing-machines.html)